# How to change theorem definition

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, chapters, newtheorem, renewcommand

Please my first theorem which I want it to be Theorem 1.1 happens to be in Chapter 2 and as thus it reads Theorem 2.1 as opposed what I want. I mean Theorem 1.1, please how can I change this? By always defining what I want in the theorem number and sections.

Comment: The (composed) number after “Theorem” is supposed to help readers into finding it. What would be the meaning of the first 1, given that the theorem is in chapter 2?

Comment: I'm working for someone and he claims since it is the first theorem to appear in the project, it should be tagged Theorem 1.1 despite it appearing on the second chapter.

Comment: And what about the following theorems?

Comment: @Memristor -- 1.1 doesn't make any sense.  Just a single number, 1, *would* make sense, and then just number equations consecutively through the document.  Maybe you could try some logical persuasion.

Comment: @egreg. The following theorems can then follow as Theorem 1.2, Theorem 1.3, . . . in that order.

Comment: @Memristor -- If the third theorem is stated in chapter 4, what is the theorem number supposed to be?  1.3 or 3.3?

Comment: ...so when does the theorem count switch to Theorem 2.1, Theorem 2.2, ...? If never, then the `1.` prefix is superfluous, would you agree?

Answer (score 1):

This is completely illogical, but the customer's always right.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\thechapterminusone}{\the\numexpr\value{chapter}-1\relax}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\thechapterminusone.\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{theorem}\label{test}
Some people have weird requirements.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
See the numbering of theorem~\ref{test}.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just remove the definition of `\thetheorem` if logic becomes active again.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. So, how will the Lemma, Examples and the rest will now go?

Comment: @Memristor It depends on whether they're numbered autonomously or share the counter with theorems.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. The assistant came in handy. I'm grateful.

Comment: @Memristor If you are satisfy with the answer, then kindly accept it by clicking the `tick` mark symbol